# Mask / rewrite SERVER_NAME for fastcgi depending on server_name directive

Tags: php, nginx

I have a PHP website that uses subdomains for each user.

I want to be able to internally route `cname.otherdomain.com` to `otherdomain.domain.com` and pass this to PHP.

Currently I have this

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name cname.otherdomain.com;
  rewrite ^ $scheme://otherdomain.domain.com$request_uri; 
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>[a-z\_\-\.]+)?\.?domain\.com$ "";

    root g:/www;
    index index.php;

    #error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;

    location ~ (?:application|modules|system) {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri;
    }

    location ^~ /index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $http_host;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9999;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide this from the user, you need to keep it within a single server block. You could create a server block which captures the *subdomain* and reuses it with the `fastcgi` location block:

```
server {
    server_name ~^cname\.(?<subdomain>.+)\.com$;
    ...
    location ... {
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $subdomain.domain.com;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    ...
}
```

Large amounts of duplication within `nginx` configuration files can be managed with `include` statements.